# db_select get all results count when also using a pager

Tags: database

Is it possilbe to get the count of all rows, when using a pager in a db_select query?
 My pager is the following:

```
$query = $query->extend('PagerDefault')->limit(20);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use `setCountQuery` if you need to define a count query to return the total number of rows in your resultset.

[See the docs for PagerDefault::setCountQuery()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/PagerDefault%3A%3AsetCountQuery/7)

Comment: How do you get access to that result though? As far as I can tell it's never made available to the `PagerDefault` class. The query is executed in `PagerDefault::execute()`, and the result isn't stored on the class. You could execute the `countQuery()` again, but that's an extra query. The only place I can see that you could get it from is one of the global pager variables

Comment: Ya, i'm not 100% sure. I have used setCountQuery before, and I think I ran the query again. Although with proper mysql query cache settings running the query again really shouldn't affect the db much as the cached query can be used ...

Answer (score 0):

It can be considered as Conditional pager. For example, depending on value of $pager, when all results are needed `$pager='all'`.

```
   if(is_integer($pager)) {
     $query = $query->extend('PagerDefault')->limit($pager);
   }
```